# image display in codeigniter shows error

Tags: image, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I am relatively new to Codeigniter, basically I choose CakePHP to develope applications. Now I am editing a Codeigniter Project, build in version 2. I have some images in my table and I need to disply it. 
I have created a helper file `general_helper.php` in which I have a function

```
function image_url(){
   return base_url().'uploads/';
}
```

So in view page , I tried to display image by

`<img src="http://localhost/myapp/uploads/vendors/images/Desert.jpg" />`

My directory structure is :

```
myapp
 -uploads
    -vendors
       -images
       -logos
```

But its not showing the image ! When I tried to put the image path in the `url`, it shows `404` error :( whats wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Codeigniter base_url function requires folder path relative to site's base url passed as parameters. Please try use below code.

First in constructor, please load your library -

```
$this->load->library('general');
```

Then please pass your uploads directory as parameter to base_url

```
function image_url(){
   return base_url('uploads/');
}
```

If images are not uploading please do check image type.
Also try use log_message('info','info_message') function to record base url.
Please refer http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/errors.html